# How to properly use socket.io and oop

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, socket.io

I love node.js and socket.io because they are mighty and beautiful, but little issue stops me with my development. It's probably because I have not enough practice with node.js an javascript at all.

The issue:
There is a code:

```
var express = require('express');
var sio = require('socket.io');
var X = require('./js/x.js');
var Y = require('./js/Y.js');

var app = express.createServer();
var ws = sio.listen(app);
var users = [];

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

ws.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    users.push(new X(socket));
    if (users.length === 2) {
        var z = new Y(users.shift(), users.shift());
        z.listen();
    }

  });

app.listen(9000);
```

And here are X and Y:

```
module.exports = function X(socket) {

    this.socket = socket;
    this.name = '';

    X.prototype.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
};

module.exports = function Y(a, b) {
    this.a1 = a;
    this.a2 = b;
    this.variable1 = 777;

    Y.prototype.listen = function() {
        this.a1.socket.on('text', function(msg) {
            console.log('a1: ' + msg);
            // AND HERE IS MY ISSUE:
            // I want to access a2 by 'this' but 'this' doesn't point on 'class' Y
            this.a2.socket.emit('text', 'a1: ' + msg);
            // Also i want to change value of variable, something like that:
            this.a1.setName(msg);
            // AND:
            this.variable1--;
        });

    };
```

My question is: HOW and what I'm doing wrong. I am PHP developer and I am aware of difference in my thinking. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your callback function is not a method of Y `this` will not reference Y.

Javascript is a funny language and `this` is part of the fun (http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this).

You may solve this by doing:

```
Y.prototype.listen = function() {
  var that = this;
  this.a1.socket.on('text', function(msg) {
           console.log('a1: ' + msg);
           that.a2.socket.emit('text', 'a1: ' + msg);
           that.a1.setName(msg);
           that.variable1--;
       });
}
```

Take a look at this example I copied from the blog post I just referenced:

http://jsfiddle.net/UuHgh/

It returns five, because count is referenced as an outer variable inside the closure functions.  But if you add `this.` before count inside the increment closure the result will be four. This is exactly for the same reason why your `this` does not reference Y.